# Change JButton Color in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am trying to make a game like simon: http://www.freegames.ws/games/kidsgames/simon/simon.htm#

I am making a smaller scale with only 2 buttons. I want the color to switch between 2 buttons, button1 and button2. This is in a thread because I need buttons to be clicked while this is happening. When I open the program the button color stays as-is.

Thanks for help in advance!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    public JButton button1; 
    public JButton button2;

    boolean isTrue = true;
    boolean switchColor = true;

    TestFrame(){
        super("Simon");
        initialize();

        this.setSize(200, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initialize() {
         this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 

        button1 = new JButton();
        button1.setBackground(Color.green);
        button1.setSize(200,200);

        button2 = new JButton();
        button2.setSize(200, 200);
        button2.setBackground(Color.blue);

        this.add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(button2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        Thread t = new Thread(r1);
        t.start();

    }
    Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(isTrue){
            if(switchColor = true){
                button1.setBackground(Color.blue);
                button2.setBackground(Color.green);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                refresh();
                switchColor = false;
            } else {
                button1.setBackground(Color.green);
                button2.setBackground(Color.blue);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                refresh();

                switchColor = true;
                }
            }

        }
    };

    public void refresh(){
        this.invalidate();
        this.validate();
        this.repaint();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A number of issues stand out (shazin has addressed one), the other that scares me is you are violating the single thread requirements of Swing.  All changes to the UI must be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Instead of using a `Thread`, you should be using a `javax.swing.Timer`.  This will save you the need to have to resync your updates back to the EDT.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FlashyButtons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FlashyButtons();
    }

    public FlashyButtons() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton btn1;
        private JButton btn2;
        private int count = 0;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            btn1 = new FlashButton();
            btn2 = new FlashButton();
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(btn1, gbc);
            add(btn2, gbc);

            btn1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            btn2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    count++;
                    if (count % 2 == 0) {
                        btn1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                        btn2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    } else {
                        btn1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                        btn2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

    }

    public class FlashButton extends JButton {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
if(switchColor = true){
    button1.setBackground(Color.blue);
    button2.setBackground(Color.green);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    refresh();
    switchColor = false;
} else {
    button1.setBackground(Color.green);
    button2.setBackground(Color.blue);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    refresh();

    switchColor = true;
    }
}
```

In the above code change the following to

```
if(switchColor = true){
```

to

```
if(switchColor == true){
```

or just

```
if(switchColor){
```

And it is best to have your Runnable anonymous class inside

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    }
});
```

than using a new Thread object to create and start the thread as it will be changing the Swing UI properties.

Comment: Would you also like to discusses the fact that the OP is violating the single thread requirements of Swing